# RestTemplate , Is there a way to retry a successful request after inspecting the response body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

Is there a way to retry a request that was successful ? All the examples are pointing to Retry behaviour when there is a failure on RestTempalte. I would like to send a request, wait for the response and inspect a field in the response and retry the request if it is not the intended status . Can this be done using the RestTemplate ?
Only thing that is I am aware of is doing a thread sleep and calling the method again. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: And what about send a fail response if the controller detect the response will contains the wrong value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if Spring-Retry can help you:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/spring/using-spring-retry-to-consume-rest-services

It will retry your method if you specifiy which responses are acceptable:

Example Code below:

```
public class RealExchangeRateCalculator implements ExchangeRateCalculator {

private static final double BASE_EXCHANGE_RATE = 1.09;
private int attempts = 0;
private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

@Retryable(maxAttempts=10,value=RuntimeException.class,backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10000,multiplier=2))
public Double getCurrentRate() {
    
    System.out.println("Calculating - Attempt " + attempts + " at " + sdf.format(new Date()));
    attempts++;
    
    try {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("http://rate-exchange.herokuapp.com/fetchRate")
            .queryString("from", "EUR")
            .queryString("to","USD")
            .asJson();
        
        switch (response.getStatus()) {
        case 200:
            return response.getBody().getObject().getDouble("Rate");
        case 503:
            throw new RuntimeException("Server Response: " + response.getStatus());
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Server not ready");
        }
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Recover
public Double recover(RuntimeException e){
    System.out.println("Recovering - returning safe value");
    return BASE_EXCHANGE_RATE;
}
```